# How to Add Select2 to row Dynamically in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm using Yii2 for my developments and I'm trying to Add Rows to table using plus button.

I'm able To add new row from that. And i need to append Krajee Select2 to my appending row. is that possible? how Can I Do that?

Following is my code use for append.

```
$('#main_tbl_body').append(
            '<tr class='+row_class+' id="tbl_rw_appent_'+new_count+'">\n\
            <td><a onclick ="removeMoreCommentField(this.id)" id="a_link_remove_'+new_count+'"><img id="image_remove_'+new_count+'" src="images/minus.png" style="width: 20px;height: 20px;cursor: pointer;" ></a></td>\n\
            <td><div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">'+' <?php
     //echo '<label class="control-label">Part Code</label>';
          $data = ArrayHelper::map(Mproduct::find()
                                        // where(['P_model' => $model->relatedToVehicle->V_model])
                                        ->all(), 'idProduct', 'P_description');


                        //$items = DealerHelper::getRemainItems();
                        echo Select2::widget([
              'name' => 'part_description_1',
              'data' => $data,
              'options' => [
               // 'class'=>'textBox mobviewmargin',
                  'placeholder' => 'Select Product',
                 // 'multiple' => true
              ],
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                'closeOnSelect' => true,
                'tags' => false,
                'multiple' => false,
                                'allowClear' => false,
            ],
          ]);
                        ?>'+'</div></td>\n\
        <td></td>\n\ \n\\n\
            <td></td>\n\ \n\\n\
                <td></td>\n\ \n\
        <td></td>\n\ \n\
        <td><a onclick ="addMoreCommentField()" id="a_link_add_'+new_count+'"><img id="image_add_'+new_count+'" src="images/plus.png" style="width: 20px;height: 20px;cursor: pointer;" ></a></td>\n\
        </tr>'
        );
```

Please Help me